# How to count only dash sign (-) in string using php?

Tags: php

How to count only (-) in string using php ?

normally i usually use below code to count all char length in string using php

```
$count = mb_strlen( $string );
```

But i want to know how can i count only dash sign `(-)` in string using php ?

EG:

```
$string = "1-2-3-4-5-";
```

after count dash sign `(-)` result will be `5`

Comment: `echo substr_count("1-2-3-4-5-", '-');` outputs `5`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most simple is use the function `substr_count()`

```
$str = 'some-class-of-css';
echo substr_count($str, '-'); //3
```